# Using Axios in Nativescript App for User Authentication

Tags: authentication, promise, axios, nativescript

I am building an app using Nativescript-Vue that requires authentication of users in order to use the app.  I have a RESTful backend that functions appropriately as tested with Postman.

JWT Tokens are implemented with a perpetual life but require refreshing every 5 minutes (refresh functionality - in a vaccuum -- working appropriately).

Using Axios.js for web calls.

I am stuck on how to implement basic logic for determining if the user is logged in. All Axios calls return a Promise. I have read the extended "Promise" responses a bunch, but it's not sinking into my head how to do what I want. In a nutshell, I need to pause code execution until the API can authenticate the user and this is not computing for me.

Code as follows:

**app.js**

```
// Import VUE library
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";

// This is my user handler
import {UserServices} from "./assets/js/UserServices.js"

// imported Components
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Home from "./components/Home.vue"

let user = new UserServices();
let loggedIn =  user.checkAuthStatus();

new Vue({
    render: h =>  h('Frame', [
        h(
            loggedIn ? Home : Login
        )
    ])
}).$start();
```

This isn't working because user.checkAuthStatus() is an async function that returns a promise and thus I cannot get a boolean value returned.  I know this is the problem, but I left that in the code so that the intended result can be understood.  What I don't understand is how to rewrite the code so that the designed flow is feasible using Promises.

Core logic is designed to be:

1. Check the user's logged-in status via user.checkAuthStatus().  This routine checks for a valid token (valid meaning it exists and is not expired).  If it is expired, the token is refreshed via a call to this.refresh() from the UserServices controller.
2. If a value of "true" is returned from user.checkAuthStatus() the Vue app should load the Home component (aka user is logged in), else the user should be required to login.

I can only imagine that this is a simple situation thousands of people have successfully overcome, but my brain isn't working thru it.  I get why JS needs to continue running so as not to stop the progress of the code (and that's the point of a Promise, I think?), but sometimes the code just needs to stop and wait it seems, like in a user authentication scenario.

Any help drilling down on the specifics on how to address my challenge?  Please and thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not wait until the API finishes before starting your app. Most apps load home page if a valid token is stored, after loading the home page it may asynchronously validate the token and if it's found invalid, user will be logged out of app. Alternatively you may start app with a loading screen, navigate to appropriate page once login is validated.

Comment: @Manoj - Thanks. I think the "loading" screen method makes sense and I hadn't thought of it.  So use my success/fail callbacks to redirect as necessary knowing that the waiting page will be displayed until the promise resolves.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

Check if a locally stored token exists, valid and not expired, if yes go to homepage else redirect to login.

Comment: Thank you. I am doing this, except with the added step of attempting to refresh the token if it is has expired.  Waiting for this token check and refreshing is the challenge I am facing and the crucial async component of the checkAuthStatus() routine.

Comment: if the token is stored locally you don't need to await check it; the async/await should be used only when you need to retrieve something from API. So, id token valid redirect to home instantly if not redirect to login page then when async/await gets the result redirect user depending on that result. That is if I understood correctly your issue. This is my approach in such situations.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  Though I'm still struggling with programmatic navigation from mounted().

Comment: well, I am a Vue user so I use https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue-navigator.